# Hiding and showing HTML5 elements without losing style

Tags: html, gwt

I am looking for a way to hide HTML5 elements in a way that when i will show them, they will be in the same place and with the same style.

I tried removing them from the RootPanel and adding back, but they did not reappear.

Comment: style="display:none"; or style="visibility:hidden";

Answer (score 0):

```
// before

$("#myElement").css({"visibility":"hidden"});

// after

$("#myElement").css({"visibility":"visible"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding and Removing elements should not be done more often. Its a performance concern. Each time you add and remove some elements Browser does some operations as mentioned in the [link](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_rendering_engine)

So, best way to show/hide elements is by using CSS display: None or visibility: hidden properties.

style="display:none"; or style="visibility:hidden";